# How do I get a network client's IP converted to a string in Golang?

Tags: string, go, network-programming

I'm trying to get a client IP when a connection is made to a server. Trying to use `RemoteAddr()` returns an addr-type, and while I can print to the console using `fmt.Println`, I'm trying to assign the value to a string variable.

Is this possible? Or is there a better way to pull a connected client's IP address?

Sample of the function I'm working on (the `strRemoteAddr` assignment is the problem part, but I left it in as a placeholder...):

```
func GrabInput(conn net.Conn, strFromListenerNumber string) {
    var strMessage string
    var strRemoteAddr string

    bufIncoming := make([]byte, 1024)

    strRemoteAddr = conn.RemoteAddr()

    for {
        bytesRead, err := conn.Read(bufIncoming)
        if err != nil {
            LogEvent(strFromListenerNumber, err.Error())
            return
        }

        strMessage = string(bufIncoming[0 : bytesRead-1])
        LogEvent(strFromListenerNumber+": "+strRemoteAddr, strMessage)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems just

```
strRemoteAddr = conn.RemoteAddr().String()
```

can do, net.Addr type has method String() for string representation.

Comment: This will not return IP as string (only). It will also include incoming port, and the output is even more messy if the RemoteAddr() is IPv6

Comment: RemoteAddr() returns interface net.Addr, depending on implementation, the String() call almost always returns more than ip, it includes the port as well. @mileusna 's answer is the correct way to find the IP. if your net.Conn can be of type other than TCPAddr (e.g. UDPAddr, UnixAddr), you might want to add more checks. Not all addr contains an IP.

Comment: No need to convert to string. @mileusna 's answer is the correct method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41602018/7092558

Answer (score 20):

Convert it to `*net.TCPAddr`

```
if addr, ok := conn.RemoteAddr().(*net.TCPAddr); ok {
    fmt.Println(addr.IP.String())
}
```

Comment: How can I access net.Conn object from a gRPC call like the one below,
```func (s *server) rpc_routine(ctx context.Context, arg *empty.Empty) (*pb.CmdList, error) {```